# Text-to-speech for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, tkinter, text-to-speech

How can I use text-to-speech in Python 2.7? With that I mean that someone can write a text, and this text will then be spoken with a voice by the program. With the voice it should be something like in the google translator and it should be compatible with Tkinter 2.7. Are there any modules or ways to manage this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: If you are disliking, please say **why** you are disliking, so I can improve my question.

Comment: Your question has been disliked because your question already has answers on Stackoverflow. You didn't search for an answer for thequestion. Also I'm not the one who disliked your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in **pyttsx**, it's cross-platforms too. You can read more about this from pypi [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyttsx).

And the doc [pyttsx - Text-to-speech x-platform](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: So it works very well, my only problem is, that it stops the whole program. With that I mean, that first the sound comes and only after that the program continue working. But I want to hear the sound during the program, when another action is taken.

Comment: @Duardo, first I'm glad you found it useful. I don't have the problem you mentioned here. You may post another question with what you have implemented, and ask for what you want the expected outcome. It is quite hard to understand what you're stuck here :)